# IServiceProvider.GetService() vs IServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have met such code:

```
var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope()

//Save serviceScope into the dictionary...and then    

return serviceScope != null
                ? serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>()
                : serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
```

Can someone explain me is it make sense at all? Are the any differences between these two calls? What actually `CreateScope()` do with the `IServiceProvider` internally? Or does it depends on the concrete implementation of `IServiceProvider`?